How to automate letter-specific kerning in Adobe software (Illustrator, Indesign, Photoshop)?
Sometimes I don't get the luxury of finding a freely accessible font that both conveys the look and feel I'm going for, while also being kerned so as to fill in awkward gaps or not look too dense or too spacious.
For this, I might need to manually adjust the kerning in illustrator or indesign for a variety of individual letters. But, I'm not making a one-off logo wordmark, I'm talking about an entire document with multiple pages of text.
So, if I make adjustments to the kerning of a font for various specific letter combinations, like A into Y, or O into P and so forth, is there a way to apply those kerning adjustments automatically to all text for the entire font or at least one a page at a time?

To globally adjust kerning pairs, you'd need to edit the actual font files.

Hmm, okay, I have not done that before, what specifically should I look for? What am I trying to edit? Am I writing scripts or does InDesign have a way to remember each pairing?

Well, you'd need a font editor - FontLab, FontForge, etc - nothing from Adobe will edit font files.
